# question from Onion Sex Quiz

Tags: combinatorics

The question is:

> Nine men and nine women are to be paired. How many possible pairings are there? (You may use a pen and paper.)

The answer is $362,880$ - I can not figure out how that answer came about.

Any way , I tried to work it out , at first I tried $2^{18}$, way off.  Then I thought ok only males can be with females and reverse.  So I just came up with $81$ as an answer each man has $9$ options x $9$ men.  That covers all the women in that $81$

Comment: It's the onion. Seems like the number should be $9!=362880$. Did you drop a digit when you copied the answer?

Comment: Yeah, that answer looks wrong to me too.

Comment: there were other math questions that involved a calculater , and the answer's were actually correct - there may be humor in it , but there is truth to the answer

Comment: Why don't you try doing the same exercise with, for example, 3 males and 3 females?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm wondering if: OP misremembered, the Onion forgot a digit or they were messing with people.

Comment: the answer was 362,880 in the quiz , still this is covering every combination possible , not just "pairing up" - right?

Comment: No, it counts all heterosexual pairing ups. Say each man goes to a separate room. Then the $9$ women can distribute themselves to those $9$ rooms in $9!$ different ways. @ScottSelby

Comment: Since our site is used by people of ages 13+, I have edited the post to keep it "PG13". Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $9!=9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=362880$, just the number of permutations of a set of nine members.

You can line the nine men up in any order you choose and then list all $362880$ orders in which the nine women can appear, or else do it the other way around.  Just **one** permutation for the men and all $362880$ permutations for the women, or else vice-versa.

Comment: the question said they "paired up" , that is why I originally didn't use this formula

Comment: the answer was 362,880 in the quiz , still this is covering every combination possible , not just "pairing up" - right?